Latex Bar chart with text below each bar?
I'm trying to create a graph like this:
Wanted result
But I can only get it to look like this using legend text, but I want to put the text directly below the bar graphs (like 0ms, 50ms, 150ms)
My current try
My code:
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar width=20pt,
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    enlarge x limits=0.5, % dist between x bars
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Impact of latency on gameplay, 1-5},
    symbolic x coords={Chess, Pong},
    xtick=data,
    ymin=1,ymax=5,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(Chess,1.1) (Pong,1.5)}; % 0ms results
\addplot coordinates {(Chess,1.6) (Pong,4.6)}; % 1000ms results
\legend{100ms delay,1000ms delay}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

